# SwiftUI: How to Update ViewModel from other ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building an app that pulls data from a server via API.  This API requires authentication and when that authentication fails (times out, token expired, etc.), I'd like the user to be redirected to the login page to log back in.

In my URLSession, I'm checking for the response status code.  If its a 401 error, the authentication has failed and I'd like to update the state of a few booleans that should drive the user back to the login screen.

The problem I'm running into is those booleans I want to update are in a different view model.  It doesn't seem to be updating those other view models.

Here's my main content view that directs the user through the app:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var loginVM = LoginViewModel()
@StateObject var signupVM = SignUpViewModel()
@StateObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()
@StateObject var projectVM = ProjectsViewModel()
@StateObject var accountVM = AccountViewModel()


var body: some View {
    
    if !loginVM.showLogin && !signupVM.showSignUpView && !loginVM.isAuthenticated {
        WelcomeView(signupVM: signupVM, loginVM: loginVM)
    } else if loginVM.showLogin && !signupVM.showSignUpView && !loginVM.isAuthenticated  {
        LoginView(loginVM: loginVM, signupVM: signupVM)
    } else if signupVM.showSignUpView && !loginVM.showLogin && !loginVM.isAuthenticated {
        SignUpView(keyboardResponder: keyboardResponder, signupVM: signupVM, loginVM: loginVM)
    } else if loginVM.isAuthenticated && !signupVM.showSignUpView && !loginVM.showLogin {
        TabView{
            ProjectsView(viewModel: projectVM, loginVM: loginVM)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Your Projects", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            ProjectsView(viewModel: projectVM, loginVM: loginVM)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Post a Project", systemImage: "plus.app")
                }
            AccountView(accountVM: accountVM, loginVM: loginVM)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Account", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                }
        }            
    }
}
}
```

And here in my ProjectsViewModel I'm running the service to fetch the project objects from the server and if it fails, which it does if a 401 status code, it needs to update the state of a few booleans.

```
import Foundation

final class ProjectsViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var projectObjects: [ProjectResponseObjectElement] = []
@Published var isFetchingProjects: Bool = false

func fetchProjects() {
    
    self.isFetchingProjects = true
    
    Projectservice.shared.fetchProjects { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let projectObjects):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.projectObjects = projectObjects
                    self.isFetchingProjects = false
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    self.isFetchingProjects = false
                    LoginViewModel().isAuthenticated = false
                    LoginViewModel().isLoggedOut = true
                    LoginViewModel().showLogin = true
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

It's those last LoginViewModel() booleans that don't seem to be getting updated.  The view that returns from this function is associated with the self.isFetchingProjects = false, but not the others that follow it.

Comment: Hey @John, the `LoginViewModel` instance you're creating in `ProjectsViewModel` does not communicate with the one in your `ContentView`, in other words, they don't share the same data, so when you're saying `LoginViewModel().isAuthenticated = false`, this does not update the instance in your `ContentView`

Comment: @cedricbahirwe that makes sense, but how do I handle this update then?

Comment: One of the solutions can be to use `EnvironmentObject` https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Comment: You can also look into `.onChange(of:)` modifier